# Eliminar palabra de una cadena c++

Tags: c++, string, algoritmos, char

Quiero convertir este programa que elimina un caracter de una cadena, pero que ahora en vez de eliminar solo un caracter elimine una palabra las veces que aparezca en la cadena. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
void eliminarcaracter(string V,char caracter,int n)
{int i; string aux; char letra;
    aux="";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(caracter!=V[i])
        { letra=V[i];
         aux= aux + letra;              
        cout<<letra;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{string oracion; char caracter; int n;
    cout<<"Introduzca la Oracion: "; getline(cin,oracion);
    n=oracion.length();
    cout<<"Que caracter borra? "; cin>>caracter;
    eliminarcaracter(oracion,caracter,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El algoritmo consta de 2 partes:

- Encontrar la subcadena.
- Borrar la subcadena.

Puedes hacerlo fácilmente con [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) y [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) respectivamente.

Así borras una ocurrencia:

```
string s, borrar;

int pos = s.find(borrar);
s.erase(pos, borrar.length());
```

Solo tienes que poner el código en un ciclo para borrar todas:

```
string s = "Este es un ejemplo un poco largo";
cout << s << "\n";

string borrar = "un";
int pos = s.find(borrar);
while (pos != string::npos){
    s.erase(pos, borrar.length());
    pos = s.find(borrar);
}

cout << s << '\n';
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##dU/NDsIgDL7zFHUe3BLdA7jpzbfwgqxODCuEQjwYn33CtkQTYw8FPr6fVjm365Uax7UmZWKH0GrLwaMcjuKDJURTfxQicjqB5IDspELg0DVCaAowSE1lJZ4CUs18YDhAceKAgAyRAO84OGPz1VllwUjf26KZJMrGAG2bNKkVZ8rwt9fFei99Noy0SHKsszmE66umrpw51fz7uGmDUGbC6rC47PeU3tU85GReo5eMmbVdImqD1IdbWS0@uf6nvKb@u8HmTJtGvMbxDQ).

---

Una posible implementación para la función `find` sería la siguiente:

```
int find(const string &str, const string &subStr){
    int length = str.length();
    int subLength = subStr.length();
    int matching = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (str[i] == subStr[matching])
            matching++;
        else if (str[i] == subStr[0])
            matching = 1;
        else
            matching = 0;

        if (matching == subLength)
            return i - subLength + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Básicamente, recorres la cadena viendo si cada caracter se corresponde con uno de la cadena a buscar (`str[i] == subStr[matching]`). Por cada uno que coincida se aumenta un contador (`matching++`).

Cuando las cadenas dejan de coincidir (`str[i] != subStr[matching]`) el contador se reinicia (`matching = 0`). Es posible que el primer caracter de la cadena buscada sí coinciada (`str[i] == subStr[0]`). En tal caso el contador se reinicia, pero a 1.

Puedes probarla [aquí](https://tio.run/##tVO7bttAEOz5FRsFiEnQMpTWkty4dREgSGWpOB9X1NrHPfkeUR7QJ6UI8gn6MOWOD1FWhBSGzGbJ2dnZndujXK2GpZS73XtiqXyBMCFtnUFR3SQ9FhDi8iZJvA0RWFRoV0IiWFeMk4TYwYK4SKVm66Bhw4cQL@EI8g@fncl@JhCeWKaQS7eEaWRcNR9pNt6nA/9uz6hrT5Aq4eQyyk9hFKaJ8EIbSGOOajCESdsqvOd5O0AtsIA09L6nOUy7Hved4jzb8@LTwXk@3uOoLJ4kNZ5e6o7m7Xxd55487b2@bGrQecPBwfDgNHL42IywafRa0jCgm2YflSBOW5/rJSmE1BmPB87bndRbaubrXUntHUwmMLgVBbK4hkGfK9EpYkwl8WWszv4tC2gMFzO@ODL8LlRl3bijg@RRRxCAHO6OM8L8p3tznU4MUCdePcMnbUnS9g@H1hGoL/fBQWU1a8YzHnRr2Ox2Xxgefamthh@@0hB@nBVtfwv4Dk@0JnggZFiY7S8NaAG/PXuy5HRIswal8GswraReanWVNDpJrfgWmudRjALn1CvwnGpreqK/).

---

Para la función `erase`, sabes que si la cadena es lo suficientemente larga tienes que reemplazar los caracteres desde la posición (`pos`) indicada por los que se encuentran un número de posiciones más adelante (`count`).

```
void erase(string &str, int pos, int count)
{
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= str.length())
        return;

    int max = count;
    int length = str.length();

    for(int i = pos; i < length; i++)
    {
        str[i] = str[i + count];
    }
}
```

Hay un pequeño inconveniente. Es posible que la cadena no sea lo suficientemente larga y que la posición `i + count` esté fuera de rango. Así que puedes crear una función que devuelva el caracter si es válida sino otro:

```
char at(const string &str, int pos, char notFound = '\0'){
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= str.length())
        return notFound;

    return str[pos];
}
```

Algo curioso es que al modificar la cadena directamente los cambios de tamaño no se ven reflejados en las funciones [`length` y `size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). Para arreglar esto puedes llamar la función [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) con el nuevo tamaño y problema resuelto. *No necesitas hacer esto si trabajas con cadenas de caracteres no administradas (`char[]` o `char*`).*

Aplicando estos cambios la función queda así:

```
void erase(string &str, int pos, int count)
{
    int length = str.length();
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= length)
        return;

    for(int i = pos; i < length; i++)
    {
        str[i] = at(str, i + count);
    }

    str.resize(length - count);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##tVTLchoxELzrKyakKuzWggtfw@OSqpxyS@VkOIjdASZeJCJpTWKbT8oh3@API6PVPgATFweiC2Kmp6enR5BuNv1lmu7370mleZEhjEhbZ1CuJ6KNcYTU8jBCDo102kyEKCznQMk12o1MEazLhkKkK2lAuijVyjoIBPCBP3tAysFG2x6UGKXdZ12oDMbQnQ668ZMAPrSAiDEwggE8P3s4TMae5iZHtXSrKI5LnD8GXWFUQ8TND6JccsfVs6HYCfGgKQMWbjE6r8hfUiZxsah0cCB0hOP2wzdkBsypwErXQpvIsxITMn7Il1FVwfckCWVPTbEfgGYMZjODWEgqjUHDLvB6cQYtPWJUCe43MIb4lgtS2bmFnISK@Vdn4svm5zTjvzSIsvYMaC1duvL0Yxi0RkDjxOC1D60F3uXahrrHXc04a332pw4nybCJY27xLCjMdMw7mFX66s4teNzOety0emvElrduJHB7tKAK1L9t9rGWpKJqzu2KcoTImQLjo@X7zuWWgr52Kl6ug9EIOp9khkp@hE6bW6LLSWGUkur56vh1GUfLaog61ddmbWU8nqrOiRPvmC6u5xgcJE@kgARU/KickeYNWeGdnVFWJvytO1XdSzU0P@teeOcHnsW904cZ/9NGmGtjZObtvNCl0qew591@/03B92KprYbHYq2B/ys39PJHwi@4py3BnFDBwrz81oAW8OePgiw5zWmlIc/xgc3LU73S@Y0IPKJk/B@c12H0BNfky/CabFu6p78).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero no quería hacerlo usando esas funciones por eso mi pregunta, quería ver como se puede hacer usando algoritmos.